# Which Data Structure to Use for KeyValue List

Tags: c#, dictionary

I'm trying to determine what data structure I need here. I have a list of fields to update in an spreadsheet. The fields are static and predictable. Example shot below (field names are more meaningful in reality than the examples shown). I may not have all values to enter; i.e. I may only be inserting data into fields "Example Field 1 - 8". I'll then use only the populated values to search for the field name and update that entry in the spreadsheet.

[image]
.

My idea was to have a `Dictionary<string, string>` with the key being the Field Name and instantiate with an empty value field. e.g.

```
public Dictionary<string, string> FieldList = new Dictionary<string, string>
    {
        {"Example Field 1", ""},
        {"Example Field 2", ""},
        {"Example Field 3", ""},
        ...
    };
```

But this seems a little clunky to me as I will have to know the full field name to add the value to the dictionary later which seems to defeat the purpose; e.g. `FieldList["Example Field 2"] = "Field 2 Value";`

My other idea was to create a class...

```
class SpreadsheetField
{
    public string DisplayName { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
class SpreadsheetFields
{
    SpreadsheetField ExampleField1 = new SpreadsheetField
    {
        DisplayName = "Example Field 1"
    };
    SpreadsheetField ExampleField2 = new SpreadsheetField
    {
        DisplayName = "Example Field 2"
    };

    ...
}
```

This option gives me nice intellisense that I can use to reference the fields. i.e. `SpreadsheetField.ExampleField2.Value = "Field 2 Value"`
I can then use the `DisplayName` property to find the field in the location in the spreadsheet I need to update. But is that overkill for what I'm trying to do here? Should I stick to a Dictionary or is there a better option? Also, for this class solution, is there a way I could make `DisplayName` ReadOnly/Const after it is set as it should not be editable once initialised.

Comment: if the key is that regular just add the # of keys you want in a for ( int num  = 1 ; num <= howmany ; ++ num ) { add to dictionary }

Answer (score 1):

Option A has the advantage of being easier to expand. You don't need to pre-populate the dictionary as, for example `FieldList["Example Field 2"] = "Field 2 Value";` will create a new entry if one does not exist. 
Option B is slightly faster (no need for a key lookup), and as you say Intellisense helps you. It does need code changes for adding/removing fields.
Your choice.

Answer (score 1):

If you use a dictionary, you could do with add only pairs that do have a value.

```
        Dictionary<string, string> dict = new Dictionary<string, string>();

//----------

        string value = "test";
        string key = "some key";

        if (dict.ContainsKey(key))
        {
            dict[key] = value;
        }
        else
        {
            if(value == string.Empty)
            {
                dict.Remove(key);
            }
            else
            {
                dict.Add(key, value);
            }
        }
```

perhaps some "classic" if/else, but it keeps the Dictionary clean and efficient, and its less code than the static written out one

In a class it can be something like:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;



  public class SpreadsheetMapper
    {

        private static readonly Dictionary<string, string> dict = new Dictionary<string, string>();

        public static void Map(string key, string value)
        {
            if(key==String.Empty)
            {
               throw new ArgumentException();
            }
            if (dict.ContainsKey(key))
            {
                dict[key] = value;
            }
            else
            {
                if (value == string.Empty)
                {
                    dict.Remove(key);
                }
                else
                {
                    dict.Add(key, value);
                }
            }
        }

        public static string Value(string key)
        {
            if (dict.ContainsKey(key) & key!=String.Empty)
            {
                return dict[key];
            }
        }

        public static IEnumerable<string> Keys(string value)
        {
            return dict.Where(x => x.Value == value).Select(x=> x.Key);
        }
    }

SpreadsheetMapper.Map("some key 1", "some value")
SpreadsheetMapper.Value("some key")
etc...
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use null conditional operator with the dictionary values so you don't have to initialize with an empty string, it checks if it's null: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/member-access-operators

Example:

```
A?.B?.Do(C);
```